# Read a file after taking user input(selection) in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to read a file after taking inputs from user - first a date and then a selection of file, but I can't get the code read any file and do anything with it. The Error message is following. Also is there a way to make this code more efficient?

```
   ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Select the execution date")
    ,dateInput("ME_DATE",label=h3("Execution Date Input"), value="2020-05-29")
    ,hr()
    ,fluidRow(column(3,verbatimTextOutput("Output_path")))
    ,hr()
    ,selectInput('selectfile','Select File in Above Location', choices=NULL)
    ,textOutput('fileselection_statement')
    ,tableOutput('selected_table')

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Location for Outputs
    Output_DIR <- "K:/Outputs/"
    Output_loc <- reactive({
                                    
    year_N_ME_DATE <- format(input$ME_DATE,"%Y")
    month_N_ME_DATE <- format(input$ME_DATE,"%m")
    month_T_ME_DATE <- months(input$ME_DATE)

    file.path(paste(Output_DIR,month_N_ME_DATE,". ",month_T_ME_DATE, " ",year_N_ME_DATE,"/",sep=""))
    })
    
    # Output Path
    output$Output_path <- renderPrint({ Output_loc() })

    # files list
    Updated_Output_files_list <- reactive({ list.files(Output_loc()) })

    observeEvent(input$selectfile, {    
    updateSelectInput(session, "selectfile", choices=Updated_Output_files_list())
    output$fileselection_statement <- renderText({paste0('You have selected: ', input$selectfile) })

    })
    selectfile <- reactive(get(input$selectfile))
    output$selected_table <- renderTable({  read.csv(paste0(renderPrint({ Output_loc() }),renderPrint({ selectfile() }),sep="")) }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `observe` blocks don't output anything, I don't think your `file.path(..)` is going anywhere. Perhaps you should convert that block into a `myfile <- reactive({...; file.path(.);})` and then later open `myfile()` or similar. (You will likely benefit from `req(file.exists(myfile()))` before trying to read the file.)

Comment: It's working till `output$fileselected` as I can see selection with "You have selected...", but unable to show the contents. On `file.path()`, isn't `Copied_Source_Files_loc` taking it's value from it?

Comment: `observe` blocks don't *return* anything, so while the block does evaluate `file.path(.)`, *it goes nowhere*.

Comment: I took the observe out and updated the code as below, but still couldn't get it to work
`  output$selected_table <- renderTable({
  file_2read <- input$selectfile
  ext <- tools::file_ext(file_2read$datapath)

  req(file_2read)
  validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))

  read.csv(file_2read$datapath, header = input$header)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and change to reflect what you have changed. Thanks!

Comment: Edited above, please help!!! A working code, if it's not too much to ask would be a great help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (Since changed) Make the block containing `file.path(.)` a `reactive` block and assign it to something so that other reactive components can use it. In your case, you changed it to `Output_loc`, so other blocks will refer to it as `Output_loc()`.
2. Similarly, you cannot put `output$... <-` assignments or `render*` calls inside an `observe` or `observeEvent` block. So we'll move your `output$fileselection_statement` outside of the `observeEvent`.
3. `renderPrint` is its own rendering function, on the same level as `renderTable`. You cannot nest them. In this case, I'm just going to remove them from inside the `renderTable` call, they make no sense there.
4. This case did not need `selectfile <- reactive(get(input$selectfile))`, there is no apparent gain in that indirection. Just use `input$selectfile`. Removed.
5. After fixing all of the above, it is also the case that you were updating the `selectInput` every time the `selectInput` was changed, which is incorrect (and completely disallows any real use of this). Instead, you want to update it when the `Updated_Output_files_list()` changes.
6. Also, instead of repeatedly concatenating the path together to create the file to be read, I use `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)`. This will be a named vector, where the values are the full path and filename, but the names will be just the filename (no leading path). This useful because `selectInput` *displays* the name but *returns* the value (full path). There is rarely a time when I think *not* specifying `full.names=TRUE` is the right thing (I cannot think of any right now).

Here's a working copy. It is not perfectly-awesome, there are still areas where some grooming might be in order.

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Location for Outputs
  Output_DIR <- "K:/Outputs/"
  Output_loc <- reactive({
    year_N_ME_DATE <- format(input$ME_DATE, "%Y")
    month_N_ME_DATE <- format(input$ME_DATE, "%m")
    month_T_ME_DATE <- months(input$ME_DATE)
    file.path(Output_DIR,
              paste0(month_N_ME_DATE, ". ", month_T_ME_DATE, " ", year_N_ME_DATE),
              "/")
  })
  # alternative
  # Output_loc <- reactive({
  #   file.path(Output_DIR, format(Sys.Date(), format = "%m. %b %Y"))
  # })
  
  # Output Path
  output$Output_path <- renderPrint({ req(Output_loc()) })

  # files list
  Updated_Output_files_list <- reactive({
    lf <- list.files(Output_loc(), full.names = TRUE)
    names(lf) <- basename(lf)
    # in this example, 'lf' is now:
    # c(iris.csv = "K:/Outputs/05. May 2020/iris.csv", mtcars.csv = "K:/Outputs/05. May 2020/mtcars.csv")
    # ... the *name* will be displayed in the selectInput, but the
    # *full path* will be the value of the selection
    lf
  })

  output$fileselection_statement <- renderText({
    paste0('You have selected: ', input$selectfile)
  })

  observeEvent(Updated_Output_files_list(), {
    updateSelectInput(session, "selectfile", choices = Updated_Output_files_list())
  })

  output$selected_table <- renderTable({
    req(input$selectfile)
    read.csv(input$selectfile)
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. I can see a lot of changes which I couldn't on my own, so a big thank you!

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, so I edited out that part.